# How to mapping the relationship Store <- Stock -> Product with OpenJPA?

Tags: java, sql, mapping, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I have the next relationship:

[image: Relationship]

Currently, I have the next code:

```
@Embedded
public class StockPK implements Serializable {

    private int storeId;

    private int productId

}

@Entity
public class Stock implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StockPK id;

    private int cantidad;

    @ManyToOne
    private Store store;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

}
```

But the DDL generated (I'm using OpenJPA in TomEE) adds two aditional fields.

```
CREATE TABLE STOCK (
    productId  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    storeId    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    quantity   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_ID INTEGER         ,
    STORE_ID   INTEGER         ,
    PRIMARY KEY (productId, storeId)
)
```

How should specify this relationship?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html. But I strongly adise you to avoid composite primary keys, and to add an autogenerated ID to your Stock entity.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. But... How to avoid duplicates with your proposal?

Comment: By adding a unique constraint on `(storeId, productId)`.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm using MySQL. Is there an effect on performance if I use a composite primary key? In another way, using `MapsId` works. Thanks!

Comment: An index on a single numeric key is faster than an index on two keys. But the main disadvantage is not performance. It's usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks JBNizet :) — The solution was as follows:

```java
@Embeddable
public class StockPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "store_id")
    private int storeId;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String productId;

    // Getters, setters, hashCode, equals

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StockPK id;

    @MapsId("storeId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Store store;

    @MapsId("productId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int quantity;

    // Getters, setters

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class Store implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    // Other fields, getters, setters ...

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    // Other fields, getters, setters ...

}
```